# Cisco IOS-XE CORS Issue - Username for csr_mgmt Virtual Service

Tags: cisco

`virtual-service connect csr_mgmt console` brings up a login prompt.  Anyone know the credentials?

My issue is I am trying to use the REST API which first requires you to authenticate for a token.  cURL works fine but I would prefer to use a browser and our friends at Cisco failed to set the CORS header ‘`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`’.  I was hoping to get at the NGINX within the service container (VM) running on IOS-XE and set that...

BTW, disabling CORS on the browser for dev/testing does not work, and the fetch api ain't fully baked (with `no-cors`) yet either.  Setting up a host file (so I can spoof the ip address to be a URL on the same origin/domain) don't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...when the scalpel fails, pick up the axe and hack!  [CORS Bypass plugins](http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-bypass-cors-errors-on-chrome-and-firefox-for-testing/); Yes...!

Good lord, that was a multiday journey through the innerds of XHR and Fetch.

[image]